# How to filter strings from an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, string, collections

I have an array of objects like this:

```
 object[] test = {
        "Rock Parrot",
        "Crimson Rosella",
        "Regent Parrot",
        "Superb Parrot",
        "Red Lory",
        "African Emerald Cuckoo",
        1,2,3


};
```

How do i filter this array and get only an array of strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var stringsOnly = test.OfType<String>().ToArray()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Could it be because OfType is missing parenthesis?

Comment: thats great @Blorgbeard ... i also tried this   var stringOnly= Array.FindAll(test, x => x is string);   which one do you think is better on resources.

Comment: I imagine that practically speaking both are "fast enough". If you are concerned, I suggest you [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) :P

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] stringArray = test.Where(element => element is string).Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: Thanks Blorgbeard - fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
object[] test = {
        "Rock Parrot",
        "Crimson Rosella",
        "Regent Parrot",
        "Superb Parrot",
        "Red Lory",
        "African Emerald Cuckoo",
        1,2,3};

List<string> s = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in test)
{

    if (typeof(string) == item.GetType())
        s.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

If you run this code the response:

```
Rock Parrot
Crimson Rosella
Regent Parrot
Superb Parrot
Red Lory
African Emerald Cuckoo
```

You can convert to array :

```
var a = s.ToArray();
```

Comment: This will crash if there are any `null` values in the array.